# Display two totals with different currencies on invoice Odoo 15

Tags: odoo-15

could you help me? I need to show two totals, one with the system currency and another with the other currency that is handled, on the invoice.

Answer (score 1):

1st: define two fields, one Float/Monetary and other for new currency(Many2one to `res.currency`).

2nd: use `_convert` method from `odoo/addons/base/models/res_currency.py` line 241, this method returns your desired amount converted in the new currency.

I hope this answer can help you.